# How can I do bookmarking in GWT with user search queries

Tags: gwt

I am newbie to GWT, but I did enough search to understand that I can use History Mechanism to do bookmarking in GWT.

But I am still confused how can I do bookmarking when I need to apply them to user search queries.
e.g. Main page may have several tabs ( I can use history mechanism here to bookmark the tab).
After the user navigates to a particular tab and performs some search query. Now if he wish to bookmark this search result URL, how can I do this with GWT.

some options I tried: GWT HyperLinks Widgets , Anchors, UrlBuilder
But I am really not sure about most convenient one.

Any inputs would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Docs on GWT History [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory).

As an example for your case, let's say you want to remember what tab the user is on (parameter t) and what query the user has searched for (parameter q). You will put in your url something like

> ## t=2&q=hello

Then when your GWT module is loading. Check the url to see if these parameters are here. If yes, parse them to load the correct tab and search. If not, load from scratch. Sample theoretical code :

```
private int selectedTab;
private String query;
 
public void onModuleLoad() {
    String token = History.getToken();
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(token)) {
        // parse the history token
        String t = token.substring(2,3);
        String q = token.substring(6, token.length());
        int tabIndex = Integer.valueOf(t);
        setSelectedTab(tabIndex);
        search(q);
    } else {
        // init from scratch
        setSelectedTab(0);
    }

    // Add a listener to your tab panel, to change the History token everytime the
       tab changes
    tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>(){
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
             selectedTab = event.getSelectedItem();
             setSelectedTab(selectedTab);
             changeHistoryToken();
        }});        

    // Add listeners for your search query stuff
}

private void changeHistoryToken() {
    History.newItem("t=" + selectedTab + "&q=" + query);
}

private void setSelectedTab(int index) {
    // Set the selected tab
}
```

The point of it is, everytime the state of your application changes, you add a new item to History. This item is a string that represents the state of your application. Then, when you load your application, check to see if this token is here. If it is, initialize your application by parsing the token and setting the correct values (selected tab, search query, whatever else). If there is no history token, then init with default values.

Don't forget to enable History support by adding this iframe to your page :

```
 <iframe src="javascript:''"
      id="__gwt_historyFrame"
      style="width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks jonasr for a prompt reply.... i already tried above approach only difference being I have to add History token from seperate places as my query is not from the same page where I select the tab.
So my tab navigation is done through a place controller and my search method requires a RPC call of which I dont have the instance. Is there a way to hack the default methods in PlaceController to make them interpret our token.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use History Mechanism to store the search query. You url might look like this:

```
  http://host.html#tab=<tabname>;search=<query>
```

If you use a [HyperLink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) widget the History is automatically updated.

Comment: I got the URL right... i am able to navigate to the right tab... but i am not able to fire the search query on that tab page as it is controlled by PlaceHolder mechanism and I am not able to make a search service call.